# Saving/updating Hibernate Entities with many-to-many relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, save

I am currently trying to solve a problem, that I have using Hibernate 4 in a Java Swing application while having several many-to-many relationships between entities.

For example, the *Project* entity has a relationship with *Person*. *Person* and *Project* have a many to many relationship. A *Project* can be in many *Categories*, so there is a many-to-many relationship as well.

```
Person *-----* Project *-----* Category
```

When I have a swing form where I can edit all this information about a *Person*, a *Project* and a *Category* and it comes to saving the *Person* when the user hits the "save" button, what would be a possible solution to save/update *Person*?

```
void savePerson(Person p){
   Session sess = factory.openSession();
   Transaction tx = null;
   try {
       tx = sess.beginTransaction();

       // steps to be done

       tx.commit();
   }
   catch (RuntimeException e) {
       if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
   }
   finally {
       sess.close();
   }
}
```

Because there is also a ***collection*** of *Projects* inside *Person* and a ***collection*** of *Categoy* inside *Project* that might have been changed, do I have to do a recursive type of saving (first save/update all the sub-entities that the collections contain and then save/update the Person entity) or do I have to only save the Person entity and Hibernate applies the save/update mechanism to the whole entity-tree with Person as the root? Any best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`CascadeType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html). You can set the behaviour for save/update operations directly by using the CascadeType in the relationship annotation:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Comment: Thanks for yout hint, this annotation is the key to get to the behaviour I described above. But it took me weeks to find out that another annotation with the most idiotic naming it possibly could have was needed get this working properly. The attribute "inverse=false", what simply represents the responsible side of the relationship is also needed.